# How to customize the Spinner (dropdown list) Graphics

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-spinner

i've been trying and searching around for customizing my spinner
this is my code

```
menu.add(Menu.NONE, 0, Menu.NONE, null)
        .setActionView(R.layout.spinner_layout)
        .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);
```

this is the the layout xml

```
    <Spinner
     android:id="@+id/spinner1"
     android:layout_width="68dp"
     android:layout_height="22dp"
     android:background="@drawable/souq_logo_en"
     android:entries="@array/activities_array"
     android:visibility="visible" />
```

and this is the look of it
well what im trying to do is to 
1- put the spanner on left
2- remove the selected item text from it and just make the wallpaper visible
3- i dont want this back color on the list i want to change it
4- i also want to control each item text color

i know its a lot
but i searched every where for this and nothing is clear 
this is the image of my app
[image: my app]
and i want to make it looks something like this
[image: the way im looking to make it]

any help?? or suggestions?